# AndroidStudio Gradle: how to configure buildTypes, and check for which buildType when building?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

How can I check if a buildType is debuggable in my **build.gradle**?

I want to do something like:

```
if(debug) {
     file.write("xxxxx")
}
```

in my build.gradle

Also, how can I build a debug and release buildType from AndroidStudio? I don't mean from command line by typing `./gradlew assembleRelease` or `assembleDebug`, I mean from the IDE itself when you press the play button. Is this possible?

I have buildTypes configured as such in my android block:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.storeSign
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode 1100
            versionName "1.1.00"
        }
    }
    debug {
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode 1201
            versionName "1.2.01"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did putting a defaultConfig{} in each buildType work for you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How can I check if a buildType is debuggable in my build.gradle?

You can do so using the buildType's debuggable flag. The end result might look something like this:

```
android {

    buildTypes.all { buildType ->
        println buildType.name
        print "Debuggable: "
        println buildType.debuggable
    }
}
```

> Also, how can I build a debug and release buildType from AndroidStudio?

Click the "Build Variants" button in the lower left corner of Android Studio to open up the Build Variants panel. From there you can select the build variant that you want to use when you run/debug.

[image]

Comment: Thanks fro your response. After selecting debug/release from the build variants tab, do you just press play and it will build the appropriate apk?

Comment: Yes, the play and debug buttons install the variant you select here.